# What am I doing wrong when training a model?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I solve the following problem: `

> We have collected more data on cats and dogs, and are ready to train
> our robot to classify them! Download a training dataset https://stepik.org/media/attachments/course/4852/dogs_n_cats.csv and train the
> Decision Tree on it. After that, download the dataset from the
> assignment and predict which observations belong to whom. Enter the
> number of dogs in your dataset. A certain error is allowed in the
> assignment.

I trained the model:

```
import sklearn
import pandas as pd
import numpy as nm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, cross_val_score

df = pd.read_csv('dogs_n_cats.csv')

X = df.drop(['Вид', 'Шерстист'], axis=1)
y = df['Вид']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, train_size=0.67, random_state=42)

clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='entropy', max_depth=4)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

After that, I downloaded the dataset from the task https://stepik.org/api/attempts/540562013/file and began to determine the number of dogs in the dataset:

```
df2 = pd.read_json('we.txt')

X2 = df.drop(['Вид', 'Шерстист'], axis=1)
y2 = df['Вид']
X_train2, X_test2, y_train2, y_test2 = train_test_split(X, y, train_size=0.67, random_state=42)

df2_predict = clf.predict(X2)
l = list(df2_predict)
l.count('собачка')
```

The number of dogs in the task should be 49, but after executing l.count ('dog') I get 500. What am I doing wrong when training a model?

Comment: We cannot download your second file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a typo. In your snippet, you're using the first dataframe to create `X2`.

I cannot access the second file, but changing this line should do the trick:

```
X2 = df.drop(['Вид', 'Шерстист'], axis=1)
-->
X2 = df2.drop(['Вид', 'Шерстист'], axis=1)
```

Besides that, you're already provided with a training set and test set, so none of the calls to `train_test_split` should be necessary.